# from a string that contains country name and it's abbreviation, how to extract only the name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example in 'GER Germany' Or 'IT  Italy', I need only the country names 'Germany' or 'Italy'.
Can I use patindex and then substring? If then, how do I check just for abbreviations? Because in the DB there are other names such as 'Viet Nam', 'Egypt' etc. And they should be displayed just as they are.

Comment: what all the things you have tried till now?

Comment: case when PATINDEX('%[A-Z]__ %',[Country_desc])=1 then 
SUBSTRING(country_desc, (PATINDEX('%[A-Z]__ %',[Country_desc])+4),30)
else 
country_desc
end as country...   But of course this doesn't work on 'Viet nam' as it does on 'egypt'

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Do you have a list of alle your abbreviations? Are these codes in capital letters always?

Comment: All the abbreviations are in capital letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be enough to check, if the second charater is capitalized:

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(Country VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @dummy VALUES('IT Italy'),('GER Germany'),('Viet Nam');

SELECT Country
      ,CutOff.Abbr
      ,CutOff.CountryName
FROM @dummy 
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING(Country,1,CHARINDEX(' ',Country)-1) AS Abbr
                  ,SUBSTRING(Country,CHARINDEX(' ',Country)+1,9999) AS CountryName) AS CutOff
WHERE ASCII(SUBSTRING(CutOff.Abbr,2,1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90
```

returns

```
Country     Abbr    CountryName
IT Italy    IT      Italy
GER Germany GER     Germany
```

### UPDATE

Get a list with the names resolved:

```
SELECT Country
      ,CASE WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(Country,2,9999)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 THEN SUBSTRING(Country,CHARINDEX(' ',Country)+1,9999) ELSE Country END AS CountryName
FROM @dummy
```

returns

```
Country     CountryName
IT Italy    Italy
GER Germany Germany
Viet Nam    Viet Nam
```

### UPDATE 2

You might [read this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15307.patindex-case-sensitive-search.aspx) to find how one can use `PATINDEX` on connection with `COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN` to allow a case sensitive search patter. The obvious solution with a collation with `_CS_` would not work with a letter range regrettfully...

Comment: The above case statement worked perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you normalize your data and put the information in 2 columns.

This will solve the issue as described.

```
DECLARE @t table(col varchar(50))
INSERT @t 
VALUES('Viet Nam'),('GER Germany'),('Italy')

SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN col like lft collate Latin1_General_BIN 
    THEN stuff(col,1, len(lft)-1,'')
    ELSE col
  END Country
FROM
  @t
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT upper(LEFT(col, CHARINDEX(' ',col+' ')))+'%' lft) z
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/633480/extract-country-from-column)**